# What should I choose between jsonb array and jsonb map for faster querying?

Tags: postgresql, index, jsonb, gin-index

I have a jsonb column which will consist of some keys and the rows will be searchable using those keys. Considering that I will be applying GIN index on the jsonb column what should be the ideal structure for faster lookups ? A jsonb array consisting of all the items or a jsonb map where the items will be the keys.

Comment: If the items are the keys, what would the values be?

Comment: @jjanes values can be anything random. I just want to know whether the queries will be fast just because I am storing the items in a map as compared to a json array.

Comment: For me, they are the same if both are equally cached.  But race your own horses.  https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/